# Pandas Time Series - Summarise over time with unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dataframe that has a series of unique values against date time objects

[image]

Instead of having these time stamps, I want to show the unique values over time, by having the index by in intervals of say 15 minutes.

How would one go about achieving this with Pandas?

#### Using example given

```
VsDF['VS_ID'].resample('15M').apply(pd.Series.unique)
```

I am getting the array of values. I actually just want a count of how many values exist at a specific time interval, as the values increase numerically over time regardless.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.resample('15M').apply(pd.Series.unique)`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd._testing._make_timeseries()["id"]
print(s)
# timestamp
# 2000-01-01     985
# 2000-01-02     983
# 2000-01-03    1003
# 2000-01-04     962
# 2000-01-05     985
#               ...
# 2000-12-27    1034
# 2000-12-28    1000
# 2000-12-29     947
# 2000-12-30     990
# 2000-12-31     956
# Freq: D, Name: id, Length: 366, dtype: int64
print(s.resample("4D").apply(pd.Series.unique))
# timestamp
# 2000-01-01      [985, 983, 1003, 962]
# 2000-01-05     [985, 993, 1008, 1033]
# 2000-01-09     [953, 993, 1009, 1014]
# 2000-01-13    [1045, 1009, 1030, 938]
# 2000-01-17    [1018, 998, 1003, 1070]
#                        ...
# 2000-12-14    [965, 1030, 1043, 1003]
# 2000-12-18      [947, 1001, 986, 937]
# 2000-12-22      [951, 1024, 980, 965]
# 2000-12-26     [943, 1034, 1000, 947]
# 2000-12-30                 [990, 956]
# Freq: 4D, Name: id, Length: 92, dtype: object
```